# Java - Image matching? EX: Is Image1 exactly like Image2?

Tags: java, image, match

Say I have image1.png, which is identical to image2.png... how can make Java check to see if they are truly identical or not? (in appearance)

If this isn't easy, is there a library for it?

I can't find anything?

Comment: Identical to the computer or identical to a human?

Answer (score 0):

Just get it into memory as raw data and then compare bytewise.
This might not be the best way, but it is a way.

Best

Answer (score 0):

Look into Lire, http://www.semanticmetadata.net/lire/

It's a set of classes and algorithms to extract information and perform image matching.